# Configure minimum character requirement for wildcard searches on OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've seen OpenLDAP directories that have a minimum character requirement for queries on the LDAP directory and I want to set that up on mine.

For example, the following search fails:

```
(uid=*)
```

and the following search succeeds:

> (uid=abc*)

I can't remember what the error code was when it failed, but I think it was unwillingToPerform.

Does anybody know what setting I need to change to add this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to look at access control http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin21/guide.html#Access%20Control

Answer (score 0):

The first filter you specified `uid=*` is not a substring search filter, it is known as a `presence` filter and is used to filter objects for return to the client that have the `uid` attribute. The other filter `(uid=abc*)` is a substring assertion filter. See also [rfc4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511).